# Programmatically saving a product

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting a product through CSV and importing programmatically.

My description field is having `'` (Singe Quote) but this is updated as `?` in description field.

If I use `$description = mysql_escape_string($test[4]);` this is also not fixing my problem.

How can I save description with `'` (Singe Quote)?

```
     $sku = $test[0];
     $Shortdescription = $test[1];
     $description = $test[4];

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); // LOAD PRODUCT BASED ON SKU TO CHECKED PRODUCT EXISTANCE

    if($product){
        $product->setShortDescription($Shortdescription);
        $product->setDescription($description);

        if($product->save()){
            echo '<pre>'; print_r('Product Saved successfully : '.$sku);
        } else {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r('Problem in saving data : '.$sku);
        }
    } else {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r('Product Not Found : '.$sku);
    }
```

My Sample Description is

> "Sweet, milk chocolate. That’s Milkmaid Gold Selection. Skilful
>   selection of the finest coco milk with a full- flavoured taste for a
>   perfect bitter sweet balance. A unique, full bodied cocos with a
>   fragrance of milk chocolate with vanilla notes.
>
> Origins: Natural Arabica from Brazil, high quality washed Columbian
>   Arabica and Robusta from the Island of Java."

Comment: can you post your product description here ?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel updated my question with my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$test[0] = 'MEMBER';
$test[1] =  "Sweet, milk chocolate. That’s Milkmaid Gold Selection. Skilful selection of the finest coco milk with a full- flavoured taste for a perfect bitter sweet balance. A unique, full bodied cocos with a fragrance of milk chocolate with vanilla notes";

$test[4] = "Sweet, milk chocolate. That’s Milkmaid Gold Selection. Skilful selection of the finest coco milk with a full- flavoured taste for a perfect bitter sweet balance. A unique, full bodied cocos with a fragrance of milk chocolate with vanilla notes.
Origins: Natural Arabica from Brazil, high quality washed Columbian Arabica and Robusta from the Island of Java";

$sku = $test[0];
$Shortdescription = str_replace("’","'",$test[1]);
$description =  str_replace("’","'",$test[4]);

$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku, null, 'sku');
if($product){
$product->setShortDescription((html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode($Shortdescription)))));
$product->setDescription(html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode($description))));
$product->save();
if($product->getId()){
    echo '<pre>'; print_r('Product Saved successfully : '.$sku);
} else {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r('Problem in saving data : '.$sku);
}
} else {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r('Product Not Found : '.$sku);
}
```

Comment: Sorry No luck :-(

Comment: Updated ans check now.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize it is not single quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like before save it to product object

```
<?php $description = addslashes($test[4]); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry No luck :-(